# flask sql alchemy not detecting change in table column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I added a new column in my database table there are already migrations file in my folder. so after adding my column when I try to run migrations It is not creating new colum in database .

on `db init` I am getting this issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 75, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 417, in run
    result = self.handle(argv[0], argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 386, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 118, in init
    command.init(config, directory, 'flask')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 42, in init
    raise util.CommandError("Directory %s already exists" % directory)
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Directory migrations already exists
```

on `db migrate`  I am getting this

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'enterprise_backup_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'enterprise_backup(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'blacklist_tokens_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'blacklist_tokens(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

On `db upgrade` I am getting this

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

Comment: Have you verified that the column doesn't actually exist? It's a trivial thing but its gotten me in the past.

Comment: @noslenkwah yes added recently . 100%  sure not exist already

Comment: You only have to run init once when starting a new project; not on every change! What is the change that you have made in your model? Try to add a minimal example which shows the behavior!

Answer (score 2):

Delete migration folder and drop the alembic versions tables from database. Then restart your process.

This is not perfect way for this error. But it will work.